# How to make a cookieless ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Is it possible to explicitly make a cookieless request with javascript? I know you can't make a request "emulating" cookies (i.e. submitting data as a cookie value can't be done unless there is an actual cookie set with that value), but this seems to be more acceptable security-wise.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186815/suppress-a-cookie-for-jquery-ajax-requests (but the answer seems to be: you cannot).

Comment: @Thilo just an IMO: I would consider this to not be a duplicate since I'm not trying to suppress an individual cookie but rather all of them. Suppressing one (or altering any) could be considered "tampering", while performing a cookie-less request is less likely to have malicious applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choices I see are:

1. You can clear all the client-controlled cookies before making the ajax request (this won't clear server-side only cookies).
2. You can add an argument to your ajax requests that instructs the server to ignore any cookie values for that particular request.
3. You can set things up so that the ajax request goes to a server or path that doesn't have access to the cookies of interest so they won't be sent with that request.
4. If it is one specific cookie value and that value is client-controlled, then you could save that cookie value, clear it, send the ajax request, then restore the cookie value again.  Actually, I guess you could do this with all cookie values, but it's simpler to do it with just a few.

Comment: In (2) are you talking about a "functional" instruction to the server (i.e. setting up some code/server handling to ignore cookies with `?ignorecookies=true` etc.), or a HTTP protocol instruction sent as a header?

Comment: @o.v. - Something like `?ignorecookies=true`, done at the application level.

Comment: ended up with a variation of (3) - set up F5 rules to strip cookies from certain requests, cheers

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in a comment to the question, this is not possible, you do not have any control over this aspect of the browser. The only way I can think to get this to work is to set the `PATH` of your cookies to a specific directory in your domain (e.g. `host.domain.com/myApp`), and then have your ajax request be to a directory that is not a child of the directory of the `PATH` you set for your cookies (e.g. `host.domain.com/ajaxDirectory`).

A common practice to reduce request size is to have resources on a different sub-domain. This way most cookies won't be sent, but obviously that isn't an option for AJAX (unless you're using `JSONP`).

Answer (score 0):

> this seems to be more acceptable security-wise

Just ignore the cookie that are unused in the server side, or first do a request to the logout service. Another alternative is to code your server so you can override the data in the cookie with, say form encoded data in post body or request header.